Is sleep detrimental to the Righteous if it’s considered mitzvah?
I heard a person can get to a level where even their sleep is considered a mitzvah although it says in Mishna Sanhedrin 8:5 that wine and sleep of the righteous are detrimental to them.
Is this only when wine and sleep are combined, or is it wine and sleep independently of one another since how can a person whose sleep is considered mitzvah be detrimental?

Sanhedrin 72a mentions many things using the same sentence construction, but only one at a time.  Except for wine and sleep, which are mentioned together.  I would conclude they are meant to be combined.

Could be a different levels type of thing. So sleep can be considered a mitzvah if you have the right intentions, but for a righteous person it’s a better mitzvah to be learning Torah than sleeping

@CuriousYid While excessive sleep is detrimental (in the vein of שינה של שחרית mentioned in Avos 3:10), optimal sleep is ~8 hrs/night (Rambam, Dei'os 4:4, though this varies by person and age). Inadequate sleep prevents focusing on Torah learning and can be harmful to one's health. If a person sleeps enough to be well-rested and with the intention to be healthy and learn Torah with focus the next day, that is also service of HaShem (Dei'os 3:3, "ואפילו בשעה שהוא ישן אם ישן לדעת כדי שתנוח דעתו עליו וינוח גופו כדי שלא יחלה ולא יוכל לעבוד את ה' והוא חולה נמצאת שינה שלו עבודה למקום ברוך הוא").
